# Efficient way to add a tuple to a list or set only if no other permutation of that tuple is already present in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose (1,2,3,4) is already present in my list/set. when I add another tuple (3,4,2,1) which has no different elements except the ordering it shouldn't get added.

Comment: If your tuples have no repeated elements, you could store them in a `set` as `frozenset`s.

Comment: For a set, you could provide a hash function which pre-sorts the members of the tuple, and of course redefine __cmp__ or eq, whichever it is now, so they actually are counted as equal, rather than just a lot of unlucky hash collisions. The tuple will need to be its own type for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your tuples have no ordering as far as your list is concerned. Use a `frozenset` instead of a `tuple` and add those to a `set`, you'll end up with a unique list of frozensets. If the order of elements matters to you afterward, you'll have to re-create it.

Comment: you can always unpack the frozensets back into lists

Answer (score 0):

```
def add(list1, list2):
    x = set(list1)^set(list2)
    if(len(x)>0):
        return list1+list2
```